# Aot errors angular 2 different behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I'm building my angular 2 project with angular-cli. Locally I build it with no problem for prod `ng build --prod --aot`. When it is build on the server however the following errors are present:

```
...
 [1m [31mERROR in
<frontend/src/$$_gendir/app/incidents/dialog/tabs/measurements/incident.measurements.component.ngfactory.ts>
(1080,35): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
target. [39m [22m

 [1m [31mERROR in
<frontend/src/$$_gendir/app/incidents/dialog/tabs/measurements/incident.measure.form.ngfactory.ts>
(1050,89): Property 'takenMeassure' does not exist on type
'IncidentAction'. [39m [22m

 [1m [31mERROR in
<frontend/src/$$_gendir/app/shared/dropdown/custom-dropdown.component.ngfactory.ts>
(94,7): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
target. [39m [22m
...
```

Those errors are correct and should be fixed, but why is the angular compiler more restrictive on the server machine than on my local one. The versions of all libraries are fixed and every time the project is build on the server the `node_modules` folder is deleted and all dependencies are downloaded again. Why do I get different behaviour when all the things are the same. Any idea is of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you build your project locally? Are using the AoT compiler or the JIT compiler locally?

The AoT compiler needs to be more strict to know how to pre-compile your code.